# Tinymce appending extra .min in the URL

Tags: tinymce

I have tinyMce folder in the root directory of my application. Now when i run my application i see error in the browser like this :-
in the DOM tree i have ,

```
<script id="mce_0" type="text/javascript" src="../../tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.min.js"></script>
```

And in the browser console , i have this

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load: ../../tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.min.js
```

Same errors for plugins as well.

I have this ,

```
 tinyMCE.baseURL ='../../tinymce';    
    if(tinymce.editors.length > 0){  
    tinyMCE.editors=[];
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    }    
    tinymce.init({
                selector: "#"+editorId,             
                height:280,
                plugins: [
                   "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                   "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                   "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor"
                ],
```

My question is why it is appending extra .min ? If it would have just one .min then it would have worked. Do i need to specify the base_url properly ? If yes , then how ? Please suggest.